# Получает ли пользователь уведомление о "Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате"?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, чат, перенос-комментариев-в-чат

При нажатии

> Пожалуйста, избегайте развёрнутых обсуждений в комментариях. Хотите автоматически переместить это обсуждение в чат?

[создаётся](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1017275/178988) комментарий:

> Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97923/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-strawdog).

Меня смущает отсутствие в нём имени пользователя. Не знаю, получает ли соответствующий пользователь уведомление о новом комментарии, в котором его позвали в чат.

Comment: В [inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/5182157/qwertiy?tab=inbox) нету ни одного сообщения "Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате", мне кажется. Но с другой стороны, все участвующие пользователи добавляются в чаткомнату и нужного можно упомянуть там явно при необходимости. Вопрос в том, вообще нужно ли упоминать всех любых при создании чата?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, мне кажется, они раньше были именными.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, а разве из комнаты придёт уведомление, если ты в неё ни разу не заходил?

Comment: *мне кажется, они раньше были именными.* — неа, этого точно не было. *а разве из комнаты придёт уведомление, если ты в неё ни разу не заходил?* — ну так, всех участников обсуждения автоматически добавляют в комнату, поэтому они как бы доступны в ней. В любом случае это все в полне себе тестируется

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну не очень оно тестируется, система на своё усмотрение перенос предлагает.

Comment: Есть у вас хоть одно предложение от системы прямо сейчас? Давайте я там комментарий оставлю, вы перенесете, я проверю уведомления

Comment: @АндрейNOP, предлагает только когда много комментариев между 2 людьми. Это обычный перенос, а не модераторский. Есть шансы, что под этим вопросом появится, но пока не хочет.

Comment: @АндрейNOP, кстати, я проверил - год назад они именными точно не были на codegolf'е.

Comment: *Есть шансы, что под этим вопросом появится, но пока не хочет* – на мете, по моему, такого вообще никогда не предлагается

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97942/discussion-between-qwertiy-and--nop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, получает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Более того, пользователь добавляется в чат и его там можно упомянуть явно через @

Comment: Вот про собаку - вроде нельзя. Я сейчас не проверил, но вроде чат не предлагает имя на собаку. Это было через ответ на сообщение.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в любом случае, возможность упомянуть пользователя есть и он получает уведомление

Answer (score 0):

Автор вопроса/ответа получит уведомление, т.к. будет создано новое сообщение.

А вот остальные участники беседы не получат уведомлений.

Comment: Но обсуждение-то не с автором, значит это баг?

Comment: @Qwertiy скорее, [meta-tag:статус-так-задумано].

Comment: Так не может быть задумано - перенос делается под конкретного участника - если он не получает уведомление, то это какая-то фигня.